# Typescript and Node.JS combined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a working node.js server somehow written in javascript (that is not written by me) and I've decided to rewrite it using typescript, because I'm .NET guy. Is there any way to use it with node and preserve types at the same time?

**Approach a)** - successful build, but node can't run it

File PeripheryInstance.ts:

```
class PeripheryInstance {
    Type: string;
    PortName: string;

    constructor(type: string, portName: string) {
        this.Type = type;
        this.PortName = portName;
    }

    myMethod(){

    }
}
```

File Server.ts

```
class Server{
    static periphery: PeripheryInstance;
    public static start() {
        this.periphery = new PeripheryInstances("a", "b");
        this.periphery.myMethod();
    }
}
```

**Approach b)** - successful build, node is running, but I can't use "intellisense" (myMethod() on type PeripheryInstance) and the code is more difficult to read

File PeripheryInstance.ts:

```
module.exports = class PeripheryInstance {
    Type: string;
    PortName: string;

    constructor(type: string, portName: string) {
        this.Type = type;
        this.PortName = portName;
    }

    myMethod(){

    }
}
```

File Server.ts

```
var pi = require('./PeripheryInstance');
class Server{
    // pi.PeripheryInstance return (TS) cannot find namespace pi 
    static periphery: any; 
    public static start() {
        this.periphery = new pi.PeripheryInstances("a", "b");
        // myMethod is not suggested by intellisence, because this.periphery is "any"
        this.periphery.myMethod();
    }
}
```

My question is: Is there any way to use **approach a)** with node.js so I can use all perks of typed code? Or I have to use some form of **approach  b)**? Thank you for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to install typings for node and any other dependent libraries you are using: `npm install --save @types/node`

You'll also need typescript: `npm install --save-dev typescript`

And then there are a lot of tutorials to get it done the right way. This is the one I followed: https://blog.risingstack.com/building-a-node-js-app-with-typescript-tutorial/

It's nothing out of the world, except that you need to set up Typescript compilation before you run the output. Don't use `any` type anywhere in your code since that'll kill the purpose of using Typescript and you won't have Intellisense to go with it. Instead use the proper types for each method and class.

In approach A, what do you mean by Node can't run it? You should run the generated output after build. Not the typescript files, but the JS ones.

In approach B, there are some mistakes. You should not do `module.exports`. The right way is `export class PeripheryInstance{}`, for example. Also, `require` is not the right way to use in Typescript. Use the `import` syntax instead.